# Except Approval Fields Hide Users particular fields in NewForm Using InfoPath

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-online, infopath, newform

Using Infopath, I have **two-level Approval status** field that only certain users (like **managers**) can see when approving or rejecting a form. The scenario would be the following:

When User add an item in a list which triggers a workflow that notifies both the initiator that they sent in a request and a manager that a request has been made. The form submitted has an option to select what manager you are submitting your form to for approval.

That manager would then be able to go to the form and select **Approved** or **Rejected** from a drop down. The original user wouldn't have seen that field when filling out the form originally.

**Actual My Requirements:**

I have **two-level Approvals status** fields. When ever, user is adding an item in New Form (user can visible only particular field like attachments, ticket_no, status).

**Level 1 Approval** will approve or reject the form, but here level 1 approval can see the `user fields and also level 1 status filed`.

When Comes to **Level 2 Approval**, he can see the all fields of `user, level 1 approval status and also level 2 approval status fields`.

Any Suggestions, Please Help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In InfoPath,

**Step 1:-**

1. Create fields for `User`.
2. Goto `Page Design` menu in ribbon and create a new view. In that view create fields for `User fields + Level 1 Approval fields`.
3. Repeat step 2 for new view and create fields for `User fields + Level 1 Approval fields + Level 2 Approval fields`.

**Step 2:-**

4. After creating views, Now goto `Data menu=> Form Load` in ribbon.
5. Now create rule in `Form Load action`.
6. Mention condition like `status=something` then `action add switch views` in that select Level 1 Approval view.
7. Repeat step 6 for Level 2 Approval view.

By this steps, you can hide the columns in **New Form** for User + Level 1 Approval + Level 2 Approval by their fields.

For more reference: [How to create multiple views in InfoPath](https://www.fpweb.net/blog/how-to-create-multiple-views-in-infopath/)